# Add data to xlsx, that not affect user editing experience

Tags: python, excel, xlsx

I want to make xlsx file with large amount of additional data, formatted in json, that can be used by external soft for interpreting xlsx content, but can't be visible or edited by Excel user.

It should not make any visible restrictions for user though.

Is there any way to do it using python?

Comment: What sort of information do you want to enter? Would putting information in a hidden cell solve your issue?

Comment: @MWaz, thanks, that might be helpful, but I edited my question to clarify, that it's a large amount of data, so it's not very 'clean' way to split it between cells, and it can't be placed in one cell.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why can't it be placed in one cell? You can also use a hidden sheet.

Comment: @MWaz, too large, cell has restrictions on it's data length.